# Why doesn't Vim regex allow more than 9 capture groups?

Tags: regular-expression

From [`:h E65`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#E65) we can see that Vim doesn't allow more than 9 capture groups in a substitution command.

For example the following command will work:

```
s/\v(a)(b)(c)(d)(e)(f)(g)(h)(i)/\9\8\7\6\5\4\3\2\1
```

But this one with one more capture group will fail:

```
s/\v(a)(b)(c)(d)(e)(f)(g)(h)(i)(j)/\10\9\8\7\6\5\4\3\2\1
```

My question is not about *why it fails* (it's a Vim hard limit) but about **why does Vim have this limit at all?**

Also, I'm aware that a real life regex with more than 9 capture group would probably be pretty monstrous to read and to maintain but I'm still curious.

Comment: Maybe not related only to Vim: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10993346/2558252

Comment: @nobe4: Interesting! So maybe people creating these tools considered that more than 9 groups were useless...

Comment: I suppose this limit comes from vi, which inherited the limit from ed/sed. Some years ago I made a patch to support up to 99 groups, but it was not included

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt So maybe the question is not totally on topic for this site but I'm still curious to know why `ed` didn't supported more that 9. Probably because of memory limitations? And that sounds like a cool patch, too bad it wasn't included.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt A more useful addition would be to implement numeric _flags_ like in `sed`: `s/.../.../3` would replace only the 3rd occurrence of the pattern. This is probably the feature I miss the most in Vim.

Comment: @SatoKatsura there is an entry about this in the todo list and that describes the problem pretty well, search for `:s//N` I think on vim_use a mapping to achieve this was posted several years ago by A Politz

Comment: I think it was [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/EDAQl0g09XY/rJjzHI9pp9cJ)

Comment: Supporting named captures would be another way to alleviate this problem.  That being said, most times I've seen anywhere near 9 capture groups was when people didn't know they could use non-capturing groups -- `\%()`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The obvious reason is that groups with two or more digits are ambiguous: should `\12` be taken as group 12, or as group 1 followed by the string `2`?

There are other reasons related to efficiency (exponential matching time and the like).  These were a show stopper when `ed` was written.  Better algorithms have been discovered since then.

Comment: This is a good possibility, do you have any reference/reading regarding this?

Comment: @nobe4 For the ambiguity part: no, but IMO it's obvious. For the efficiency part, you'd have to read about the early implementations of regexps. It was a well-known problem at the time. I don't have exact citations, but they shouldn't be hard to find.

Comment: Indeed that sounds totally plausible.

Comment: Yes, it's almost definitely that the parser was written to look for a single digit after backslash, and never changed. This was common enough, a long time ago. Other languages have come up with ways around this (for example, only considering `\11` a reference to a capture if there are at least 11 of them, which is inconsistent but usually okay; and things like `\g{11}` for backreferences and `${11}` for substitutions), but vim has never introduced any of those.

Comment: They could maybe change the parser to look for \[0-9a-Z], this would give an additional 52 groups without ambiguity by referencing \1, \a, or \B.